# Improperly Labeled Explorer Link

Tags: office-365, explorer, onedrive

Everything was going just fine. The website is setup and the sync file has been clicked. One drive opens up and starts to download the required files from the document library then a couple of minutes into the transfer the title goes from

"DDMac Information - Active Jobs"

to

"T"

Having tried to rename it multiple times I am told the folder or file is open in another program. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an image?